# Newtonsoft.json throwing error: Array was not a one-dimensional array

Tags: asp.net, multidimensional-array, json.net

I am getting an error when trying to serialize an object products.

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";

product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);

product.Price = 3.99M;

product.Sizes = new string[3,2] { {"Small","40"}, {"Medium","44"}, {"Large","50"} };



string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);//this line is throwing an error


Array was not a one-dimensional array
```

Is there any way to serialize a two dimensional array with Newtonsoft.json

Thanks in Advance.
SIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.NET doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. Use a jagged array instead.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/workingwitharrays11232005064036am/workingwitharrays.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot King!!
I have been struggling to accomplish this since last 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Does newtonsoft support serializing anonymous objects? If so you can try:

```
product.Sizes = new {Small = 40, Medium = 44, Large = 50};
```

You'll need to change `Product.Sizes` to just be an `object`